# Conditional and delayed registration on StructureMap

Tags: structuremap

I am registering OwinContext in StructureMap:

```
container.Register(() => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext());
```

But I get the following error on AssertConfigurationIsValid:

```
No owin.Environment item was found in the context
```

I found a solution for SimpleInjector which is the following:

```
container.RegisterPerWebRequest(() => {
   if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Items["owin.Environment"] == null && container.IsVerifying()) {
     return new OwinContext();
   }
   return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext();
});
```

Can this be replicated with StructureMap 3? I can't find a container.IsVerifying in it ...

Answer (score 0):

If your context isn't being resolved during the container's registration then you can defer the resolving and execution of your dependency in StructureMap by using injecting your type in a delegate such as `Func<>`.

The dependency will then only be resolved when you invoke the function.

```
...
public YourController(Func<HttpContextWrapper> context)
{
    this.context = context;
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var contextWrapper = this.context(); // dependency is resolved at this point.
}
...
```